# Does Solana have an official Python implementation?

Tags: python, keypair, solana-sdk

I wonder if Solana has an "official" Python implementation; specially for Keypairs, or everyone is just using this repo: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/master/src/solana/keypair.py

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, to my knowledge, this is the most popular (unofficial) one, and there is not one officially supported by the Solana Foundation.

However, that unofficial one's most recent version is built with the Python package [solders](https://pypi.org/project/solders/0.1.4/), a binding to the official [Solana Rust SDK](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/). So it's close to official in that sense.

These are the officially supported clients, listed [here](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/rust-api).

[image]